# pygtk read-only gtk.TextView (make it ignore mouse clicks)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I need a way to make a gtk.TextView ignore mouse clicks in a pygtk GUI.

I have set the 'editable' property to false to prent user input, but it still responts to mouse clicks.

This textview displays some output from other commands, so if the user clicks anywhere on it, it moves the cursor to the clicked location.  I need to avoid that.

I need something similar to the set_property('sensitive', False) results, but without graying out the widget. It just needs to sit there and ignore all kinds of user input.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. For anyone who is interested, here it goes.

The truth is, there is no way to make it ignore the mouse clicks. What you can do when you want a read-only kind of text view, you set the 'editable' property to False. This ignores the keyboard input.

The other thing is when inserting text, you want to use the `insert` method rather than the `insert_at_cursor` method.

**Sample**

```
tview = gtk.TextView()
tview.set_property('editable', False)


# Insert text at the end on the textview.
buffer = tview.get_buffer()
buffer.insert(buffer.get_end_iter(), 'This text goes at the end of the existing text')
```

HTH

Comment: For future reference, you generally want to use the `insert` method rather than the `insert_at_cursor` method anyway, for precisely that reason: you never can tell where the cursor is going to be.

Answer (score 9):

What you did is better for your purposes. For future reference, though, if you actually wanted to just block clicking, you would want to connect the `TextView` to `button-press-event` like so:

```
tview.connect('button-press-event', tviewClicked)
```

and define the handler function so that it returns `True`:

```
def tviewClicked(widget,event):
    return True
```

Returning True from a handler function tells GTK not to pass it on to anything else, so the click never gets sent to the `TextView`. The user won't be able to click on it any more.

I know this is an old question, but maybe it'll help someone else who comes to this page.

Answer (score 8):

```
textview.set_property('editable', False)
textview.set_property('cursor-visible', False)
```

If you even want to allow the user to select the text or right click and choose Copy... you should overwrite `button-press-event` as @Derek Redfern wrote.